# PowerShell ExecutionPolicy and WindowStyle not usefull?

Tags: powershell

I have a simple PowerShell script (1 line) in a lnk/shortcut :

```
%windir%\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -WindowStyle hidden;cp file.jpg %temp%\file.jpg
```

Here are my questions :

1. I don't understand the utility of the parameters `-ExecutionPolicy` and `-WindowStyle` because no matter I write them or not it doesn't change anything. The script works without showing any prompt. When I run a .ps1 file I must use `-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` but here in my case I don't need `-ExecutionPolicy`?
2. Is there a way to replace `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` by `/Bypass` only?

Comment: The command-line parameters of `powershell.exe` direct PowerShell's state when it starts. I don't otherwise understand anything you are asking.

Comment: In my script, does the -ExecutionPolicy and -WindowStyle parameters are mandatory or not ? I don't understand when they are necessary and when they are not.

Comment: It depends on whether you need to specify an execution policy and a window style. If you don't need to specify them, then you don't need those parameters.

Comment: the semi-colon in your script probably renders it irrelevant. It means you run powershell which does nothing, then separately do a file copy using `cp` of whatever shell you were in before you ran powershell.

Answer (score 0):

That's a legit question:

- `powershell.exe –ExecutionPolicy Bypass` and it will start a PowerShell session that allows for running scripts and keeps the lowered permissions isolated to the currently running process. See [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy?view=powershell-5.1#required-parameters).
- `powershell.exe -windowstyle hidden` hides the PowerShell application window after it has been created by the OS when the process starts. This means the powershell.exe code that processes -WindowStyle Hidden is therefore executed after the console window is opened, and the [Powershell window is shown briefly](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3028).

In general, `powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File my.ps1` is how production scripts should be launched safely.

Enter `powershell.exe /?` and the PS prompt to show the built-in help of the available PowerShell command-line arguments.